# MySQL: creating comma separated list and using in IN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat, find-in-set

My function code is like following.

```
DECLARE ids VARCHAR(55);
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(id) INTO ids 
        FROM tableName WHERE ...;
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(id), ids ) INTO ids FROM tableName .....;
SELECT column_name FROM tableName WHERE id IN (**ids**);
```

In this i am creating id list with two select statement and applying into IN list. Its giving me null result . if i CAST the ids in like CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(id), CAST(ids as char) ) then its giving me first  row result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by the following code

```
DECLARE ids VARCHAR(55);
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') INTO ids  FROM tableName WHERE ...;
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',')AS CHAR), CAST(ids AS CHAR)) INTO ids FROM tableName .....;
SELECT column_name FROM tableName WHERE FIND_IN_SET (id, ids );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE ids VARCHAR(55);
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) INTO ids 
FROM (SELECT id 
      FROM tableName 
      WHERE...
      UNION 
      SELECT id 
      FROM tableName
      WHERE....
) AS A;

SELECT column_name FROM tableName WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, ids);
```

Comment: This is right but it would be not work in temporary table case.